# Canvas is not working on Android latest version 4+

Tags: android, canvas

I want create layer on top of the activity layout and I need make hole like rectangle or circle, something like the attached image. I did this by using SurfaceView and its working fine on lower version on android but not on version 4+

[Sample screen shot] (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3yZokwUGKFgTkM1ek1nZHNyZ2s/edit?usp=sharing)

My code is

```
public class SurfacePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    public SurfacePanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SurfacePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.CommonInit();
    }

    private void init() {
        setZOrderOnTop(true); //necessary
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(10, 10);
        path.lineTo(115, 10);
        path.lineTo(115, 260);
        path.lineTo(10, 260);
        path.close();

        canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
        canvas.clipRect(150, 30, 200, 100, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
        canvas.drawARGB(180, 0, 0, 0);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

}
```

Someone please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because ICS+ defaults hardware acceleration to true, and some of your drawing calls on the canvas aren't supported in hardware mode, check the following:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

You can turn it off in your application tag in your manifest, per activity in your manifest, or on the view itself with `setLayerType`